How to wrap div with display: inline-flex?


<div style="width: 250px; background-color: lightcoral">
<div style="display: inline-flex;">Lorem Ipsum</div><div style="display: inline-flex;white-space-collapse: preserve;">, </div><div style="display: inline-flex;">consetetursadipscing elitr, sed diam</div>
</div>

<div style="width: 250px; background-color: lightyellow">
<div style="display: inline-flex;">Lorem Ipsum, consetetursadipscing elitr, sed diam</div>
</div>



How can I style the divs in the red div so that they look like the yellow div?

Why do you use block tags instead of inline tags? Is there a particular reason?

inline-flex containers are atomic inlines, they can't be fragmented across lines in the way you want.

not sure why your are repeating the same question differently. The only way to have what you want is the solution I gave you in the previous question. There is no other option



<div style="width: 250px; background-color: lightcoral">
<div style="display: inline-flex;">Lorem Ipsum</div><div style="display: contents">, </div><div style="display: contents;">consetetursadipscing elitr, sed diam</div>
</div>

<div style="width: 250px; background-color: lightyellow">
<div style="display: inline-flex;">Lorem Ipsum, consetetursadipscing elitr, sed diam</div>
</div>



Try this it will work as you have asked

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
